# What are "breathy frocks"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> Jones’s red carpet style falls on the feminine side—think **breathy frocks** from Dior, Gucci, and Valentino—peppered with eye-catching pops. ([source](https://www.vogue.com/article/felicity-jones-charles-guard-honeymoon-floral-dress-celebrity-wedding-airport-style))

I am not sure this sentence makes sense to me. A [frock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frock), I think, just refers to a fancy dress. Breathy, according to dictionaries, means "producing or causing an audible sound of breathing, often related to physical exertion or strong feelings." How can a dress be breathy, namely, producing the sound of breathing?

Comment: It is hard to capture a style or movement in a clear and succinct way. Fashionistas, art critics, gourmands .. they all try to communicate an experience in words which they did not receive in words. It’s a tough nut. You’d have to see the specific dresses the author is describing and comparing them to to get a real sense of what they have in common. My guess, not being a fashionista, is the dresses all have a sense of roominess (like *breathing room*), an expansive and floating (weightless) quality, maybe something billowy or flouncy or otherwise *breezy*?

Comment: @DanBron is right, I think. This is more a question about technical terms in fashion that a general English language question. If there were a fashion Stack Exchange I would suggest asking there. But alas, there is not.

Comment: @DanBron Your comment would be a great answer. I put it in a community wiki answer, in the interest of keeping records. Hope you don't mind. Of course, if you would like to do it yourself or expand on your comment in an answer, please don't hesitate to do so. I will readily accept it.

Comment: @Deancue What you’ve done is perfectly  ok with me. I didn’t consider that comment an answer because ultimately it didn’t tell you what *breathy* meant in this context, only why you might not find a relevant definition in a dictionary. I made some guesses at the end, they’re so far from authoritative they’d have to catch a flight to see that word. :)

Answer (score 1):

Per a [comment by @DanBron](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/185655/what-are-breathy-frocks#comment367329_185655):

> It is hard to capture a style or movement in a clear and succinct way. Fashionistas, art critics, gourmands .. they all try to communicate an experience in words which they did not receive in words. It’s a tough nut.
>
> You’d have to see the specific dresses the author is describing and compare them to to get a real sense of what they have in common.
>
> My guess, *not* being a fashionista, is the dresses all have a sense of roominess (like *breathing room*), an expansive and floating (*weightless*) quality, maybe something billowy or flouncy or otherwise *breezy*?